# How to resolve function-generated error message

Tags: php

How can I handle the error message generated by a dreamweaver function, i need to handle the message if I am told a value that does not exist.

I made this simple test and the error message was displayed to me:

http://topdeia.com/city.ajax.php?ajax=true&search=&uf[]=27

The message is this:

> PHP Warning:  mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in

The function:

```
$theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);
```

Comment: What isn't clear about this error message?

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Hello @John Conde, i need to prevent this message from appearing.

Comment: Then make sure what you're feeding the function is a string. Also, what @JayBlanchard said.